# What does the vertical pipe slash operator do?

Tags: postgresql, operator

I'm wondering what pipe slash `|/` does in,

```
SET equal_area_radius = |/area/pi();
```

The statement works and it definitely changes the value:

```
SELECT |/125.555/pi(); --  returns: 6.32181918120139
SELECT 125.555/pi();   --  returns: 39.9653977598058
```

What does the pipe-slash operator `|/` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|/` operator calculates the [square root](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)

```
postgres>  select |/16,  sqrt(16);
 ?column? | sqrt
----------+------
        4 |    4
(1 row)
```

So `|/125.555/pi()` is equivalent to `sqrt(125.555/pi())`

Comment: Sure enough--looked at the site where I copied the statement from and they had this: https://i.imgur.com/5twDykK.png  I should have worked that one out.  Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse funny that the `|/` operator has lower precedence than `/` an `*`.

Comment: it makes sense. in math, the radical symbol, which `|/` is supposed to suggest, is often used with a long expression underneath it. this would only work if `|/` has low precedence.